# strange results javascript comparison

Tags: javascript

I have an entry level question for javascript. When executing the following the result is
false
true
Some numbers are equal
number, number

numbernumbernumber

1. Why are the first 2 values different?
2. Why is the first one wrong?

JS:

```
function sort3(a, b, c) 
{
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = 
        (typeof a) + (typeof b) + (typeof c);
    if(a > b > c) { return [a, b, c];
    else if(a > c > b) return [a, c, b];
    else if(c > a > b) return [c, a, b];
    else if(c > b > a) return [c, b, a];
    else if(b > c > a) return [b, c, a];
    else if(b > a > c) return [b, a, c];
    else return "Some numbers are equal";
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="ex1"></p>
<p id="output"></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var m = parseFloat(1);
    var k = parseFloat(2);
    var l = parseFloat(3);
    var q = typeof m;
    var w = typeof k;
    var e = typeof l;
    var res1 = (l>k>m) + "</br>";
    res1 += (m<k<l) + "</br>";
    var res2 = sort3(m,k,l) + "</br>";
    var res3 = (typeof m) + ", " + (typeof Number(m))
    document.getElementById("ex1").innerHTML = res1 + res2 + res3;
</script>
```

Comment: The input to `parseFloat` is a string. `m = parseFloat(1)` becomes `m = parseFloat("1")` which is `m = 1`. You don't have to write anything special to get a floating-point number in JavaScript. *All* JavaScript numbers are floating-point.

Comment: `</br>` is an invalid tag. For a line break, use `<br>` (or `<br/>` in XHTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do compound comparisons in JavaScript (or any other language syntactically derived from B), you don't do things like

```
(l>k>m)        // <=== Wrong
```

Instead, if you want to know if `l` is greater than `k` and `k` is greater than `m`, you use `&&` (the logical "and" operator), like this:

```
(l>k && k>m)
```

Details:

Your original expression `(l>k>m)` breaks down into this:

```
((l>k)>m)
```

which means you'll get one of these:

```
(true>m)
// or
(false>m)
```

When comparing a boolean to a number, the boolean is coerced to a number, so that becomes in effect:

```
(1>m)
// or
(0>m)
```